# Why don't the Americas use ISO paper sizes?

Tags: 20th-century, international-relations, north-america

In the mid-sixties, most countries standardized on ISO paper sizes (A-series, B-series, etc.). The Americas didn't. **Why not?**

(Around the same time there was a failed push in the US to switch to metric, but this seems like a different issue.)